# change icon of a Point in a GeoJson

Tags: python, folium

here is the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trExe.png)

I want to change the icon of this point but I can't.
I have successfully change the color of the linestring but not for the point.

Can someone help me ?

here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString


def style_function(feature):
    if 'Point' == feature.get('geometry').get('type'):
        print('point')
        icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image="Flamme.PNG", icon_size =(15,15))
        return {"icon" : icon}
    
    if 'LineString' == feature.get('geometry').get('type'):
        print('LineString')
        return {"color" : "#00FF00"}

xy1 = Point((10,10))
line1 = LineString([(30,-30), (30, 30), (-30, 30), (-30, -30), (30,-30)])

df = pd.DataFrame({'geometry':[xy1, line1]})
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df['geometry'], crs="EPSG:4326")

m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=2)
tooltip=folium.GeoJson(gdf, name="point", style_function=style_function).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

Comment: Are you importing the GeoJson file directly using folium.GeoJson(file) or via pandas/geopandas then adding to folium as in posted code here? Updated answer to reflect workaround using geojson file as source.

Comment: Hi I am import geojson file with pandas/geopandas and then after some processing I give that to folium

Answer (score 0):

Easier to customize the data if add the points and lines separately. This example adds a point marker with a custom icon and a line with a custom color to a Folium map.

```python
import folium
from shapely.geometry import LineString

folium.Marker(
    location=[10, 10],
    popup="Some Other Location",
    icon=folium.features.CustomIcon('icon.png', icon_size=(32,32))
).add_to(m)

line1 = LineString([(30, -30), (30, 30), (-30, 30), (-30, -30), (30, -30)])
geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=line1,
       style_function=lambda x: {'color': 'orange'})
folium.Popup('this is a box').add_to(geo_j)

m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=4)
geo_j.add_to(m)
m.save("index.html")
```

**Output:**

[image: folium map]

**UPDATE:**

If accessing a large GeoJSON file then *style_function* does not appear to work with point features as you're seeing. This workaround should work with any geometry (e.g. Point, LineString, Polygon, MultiPolygon, etc.).

```
import folium

def style_function(feature):
   # add your logic here to return style for non-point features
   return {"color": "#FF0000"}

m = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=8)
gj = folium.GeoJson(f)
feature_group = folium.FeatureGroup('points')
icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image="icon.png", icon_size=(32, 32))
for feature in gj.data['features']:
    if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'Point':
        # add logic here to create/apply different icons as needed
        coords = list(reversed(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
        folium.Marker(location=coords),
                      icon=icon,
                      popup='Hello'
                      ).add_to(feature_group)
    else:
        # add style_function to non-point feature
        folium.GeoJson(feature, style_function=style_function).add_to(m)

feature_group.add_to(m)
m.save("index.html")
```

Comment: Hi CodeMonkey
Thank you for your answer.
I actually do that for the test just to make sure I can change the icon.

I really want to change the icon directly in the GeoJson function with style function.
Because the GeoJson date is very large. (here I just show an exemple of 2 kind)
The Polygon and LineString works very fine but the Point does not apply even my color.
And  I did not find any example for that in the documentation.

I also see that folium.features.GeoJson has a parameter marker.
but same thing, I did not manage to make it work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Hi thank for your feedback and your help CodeMonley I really appreciate.
The thing with this methode (to separate the point and the linestring or other geometry) is that the display is split on 2 layers (1 for the point and 1 for the other geometry) 
there is king of lost of information or people have to remember to tick both layers at the same time. :(
do you think it is a bug on the library or a function not cover ?

Comment: @goanes - yes looks like a bug to me. again there are no mixed geometry examples in docs using style_function so prob never tested.

Comment: I have found this https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSONMarker.ipynb
it seems to work with standard icon but not with custom icon.
Moreover it is the same icon for every point. I have to type of point and I need one icon for each type of point.
I workaround this issue with Circle as a Marker but it does not show really great.